# Php Add days to array if the date is not consecutive

Tags: php

I have an array with dates that can be non-consecutive

```
$dates = 
    Array ( [0] => 17-06-2017 [1] => 18-06-2017 [2] => 22-06-2017 [3] => 23-06-2017 [4] => 24-06-2017 [5] => 30-06-2017 [6] => 09-07-2017 [7] => 10-07-2017 [8] => 11-07-2017 [9] => 12-07-2017 [10] => 13-07-2017 )
```

If the days are not consecutive and the interval is less than 8 days add the missing range

This is the date to add to array

```
19-06-2017 20-06-2017 21-06-2017 25-06-2017 26-06-2017 27-06-2017 28-06-2017 29-06-2017
```

The interval from **01-07-2017** to **08-07-2017** no because is greater than 8 days

if the interval less then 8 days create range $date_from, $date_to

```
$arrayRanges = $this->createDateRangeArray($date_from, $date_to);
foreach ($arrayRanges as $key => $arrayRange) {
   array_push($dates, date('Y-m-d', strtotime($arrayRange)));
}

public function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo) {
        $aryRange=array();
        $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
        $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));

        if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom) 
        {
           array_push($aryRange,date('d-m-Y',$iDateFrom)); // first entry

           while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo) 
           {
           $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours
           array_push($aryRange,date('d-m-Y',$iDateFrom));
           }
         }
           return $aryRange;
    }
```

Comment: There is no question here

Comment: Php Add days to array if the date is not consecutive

Comment: That's not a question. It's a statement. What specifically is your *problem*?

Comment: How do I retrieve the range of non-consecutive dates from this array?

Comment: check this, this may help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44457902/remove-array-list-object-if-its-dateproperty-is-with-in-15-days-with-respect-t/44459266